# How to remove/hide Firebase warning "Running in emulator mode. Do not use with production credentials" when using Flutter?

Tags: flutter, firebase, firebase-tools

When using Firebase in a Flutter app and enabling emulators for local/offline development, I cannot find a way to hide the "running in emulator mode" warning.

Enabling in flutter:

```dart
FirebaseAuth.instance.useAuthEmulator(host, 9099);
```

What you see when running on a platform....

[image: flutter 'Running in emulator mode. Do not use with production credentials']

I'm all for security, but this makes for a poor developer experience when you're working on the app and it's UX locally; straight up annoying!

Other published issues on this matter use CSS to hide the warning, but given this is a Flutter app the same approach won't work.

How else can this be solved? Thank you

Answer (score 0):

If this is happening in the web build you can use the css trick.

You just need to add the style to `web/index.html`:

```html
<body>
  <style>
    .firebase-emulator-warning {
      display: none;
    }
  </style>
... other body stuff
</body>
```